# How to used data html for system like(vote) without users change value(inspect) secure 100%

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I want to send a value (id_post) with ajax but when user changes the value to html (with inspect), the value retrieved and the new

code html

```
<button  class="bt_like" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>" >like</button>
```

code php + sql

```
<?php 
require 'init.php';

$id_post     = $_POST['post'];
$id_user    = (int)trim(htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user_id']));
$liked  = '1';

$stmt=$connect->prepare('INSERT INTO likes_emploi(id_post,id_user,liked) VALUES(:a,:b,:c)');

$stmt ->bindValue(':a',$id_post,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt ->bindValue(':b',$id_user,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt ->bindValue(':c',$liked,PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();
```

code ajax

```
$('.bt_like').on('click',function(){

var query = $('.bt_like').attr("data-id");
$.ajax({
    url : 'systemLike.php',
    method:'POST',
    data : {post:query},
    success : function(data){$('header').html(data); } /* no Important*/
});

});
```

**result with that:**

```
<button  class="bt_like" data-id="15" >like</button>
```

*everything is working* **but** 
the problem is that if a user clicks inspect (Chrome) is change value 15 to 99 database received value is **99**

Comment: Give the button an name then in your code you can check the name and  set the appropriate value to store in the database.

Comment: Why is it important to keep someone from liking post #99, if they want to? For example, is there anything stopping them from navigating to post #99 and liking it directly from there? If not, then putting security to prevent them from liking #99 when they're looking at #15 seems superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

That's inevitable in this way. But, you could obfuscate the ID, and compare with a value in session (by example).

In the PHP :

```
session_start() ;
$_SESSION['posts'] = [] ;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

    $uniq = sha1(uniqid(true).$row['id']) ; // Example could be another thing.
    $_SESSION['posts'][$uniq] = $row['id'] ; 

    echo '<button  class="bt_like" data-id="' . $uniq . '" >like</button>' ;
}
```

Finally, in the PHP who received XHR query :

```
session_start() ;
$sent_id = $_POST['post'] ;
$id_post = isset($_SESSION['posts']) && isset($_SESSION['posts'][$sent_id]) 
         ? $_SESSION['posts'][$sent_id] : 0 ;
if ($id_post) {
   // do stuff
} else {
   // Was changed by user! (or session was expired)
}
```

In this way, the ID will be different for all visitors.

Of course, it is maybe more useful to use something like `$_SESSION['posts'][...] = $id` to avoid confusions and to clear the array if you want.

Comment: 1 thank you but is there a problem, if I go for multi article on the same page ?

Comment: @z.yastos I've updated the answer with a loop around your button.

Comment: IMO, I think it's simpler to just run the query again in the ajax query and check if the id exists in the query. No need to create a hash.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Very interesting comment. I thank you. Maybe you should create an answer to explain that, also for the future readers!